# How to make text align to the right when in edit mode in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a custom formatter for a column in jqgrid, when in edit mode, it always align to the left. How can I make it align to the right?

Here is the part of colModal and custom formatter, some of the columns are editable.

```
    colModel: [ { name: 'col10', width: '70px', fixed: true, align: right',
                  formatter:percentFomatter, editable: true }, 
    { name: 'col11', width: '70px', fixed: true, align: 'right', formatter: percentFomatter, editable: true }, 
    { name: 'col12', width: '70px', fixed: true, align: 'right' } ], function percentFomatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) { return cellvalue + '%'; };
```

Comment: Please show some code - so we will be better able to help you.

Comment: Here is the part of colModal and custom formatter, some of the columns are editable.
Thanks.


colModel: [
          { name: 'col10', width: '70px', fixed: true, align: 'right', formatter: percentFomatter, editable: true },
          { name: 'col11', width: '70px', fixed: true, align: 'right', formatter: percentFomatter, editable: true },
    { name: 'col12', width: '70px', fixed: true, align: 'right' }
            ],


function percentFomatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {

                return cellvalue + '%';
    };

Answer (score 3):

You can use `editoptions:{datainit: ...` to apply style to element being edited.

e.g.

```
...
...
align: "right",
editable:true,
editoptions: {dataInit:function(e){
                e.style.textAlign = 'right';                            
             }}
...
...
```

I have created small demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/amighty/kxe1og6r/15/)